# Contour Matlab figure (saved as .eps file) is more than 150MB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, contour, contourf

I am reading a netcdf file in matlab, using ncread. Then I try to do a contour plot of my data, time variable is 3000x1, z(1,:) variable is 1x200, and the resulting  X1 and Y1 variables are both 200x3000. When i try to save the figure produced in .eps format i get a file sometimes as big as 200MB that when i try to open sometimes crashes. Am i doing something wrong with the contour plot?

```
[X1,Y1]=meshgrid(time',z(1,:));

figure
contourf(X1,Y1,precip(:,:,1)','ShowText','on');
```

Comment: No, you are not. EPS are vector data. If your data is complex, it will take memory. I suggest you just save a high res png

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I know eps  are vector data, but when i produce a pcolor plot instead of the same data and save it as .eps again its smaller notticably smaller in size. For the same data set, pcolor plot 63MB while contour plot 106.3MB. Would you expect this difference?

Comment: Because its vector plot, depends highly on the data and type of plot. It is how it is, there is no way of changing. Make your plot with less data or use another format

Comment: You can try to make a coarser grid.

Comment: But if i change the grid, it would mean that meshgrid would produce X1 and Y1 variables that will not be the same size as my precip variable hence contourf function would not work right?